# Apex Chart Zooming Difference

Tags: zooming, axis-labels, apexcharts

I cannot properly zooming on two graph in Apex Chart. Also the labels of the x-axis are different between the two graph.

I wish to achive it's to have the same x-axis label for both graph and, when i'm try to do the zooming, to get the same zoomed area for both graph.

Here the code

```
    var options = {

        series: [{
            data: dt
        }],
        chart: {
            height: 500,
            type: 'rangeBar',
            animations: {
                enabled: false
            },
            background: '0',
            id: 'gantt',
            group: 'bind',
            zoom: {
                enabled: true,
                type: 'x',
                autoScaleYaxis: false,
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            bar: {
                horizontal: true,
                colors: {
                    ranges: [{
                        from: 0,
                        to: 0,
                        color: undefined
                    }],
                    backgroundBarColors: [],
                    backgroundBarOpacity: 1,
                    backgroundBarRadius: 0,
                },
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function (val, opts) {
                var label = opts.w.globals.labels[opts.dataPointIndex]
                return ""
            },
            style: {
                colors: ['#f3f4f5', '#fff']
            }
        },
        xaxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            labels: {
                //formatter: function (value) {
                  //  var pippo = parseInt(value)
                  //  var pluto = new Date(pippo)
                  //  return pluto // The formatter function overrides format property
                  //},
                  format: 'HH:mm'
            }
        },
        yaxis: {
            show: true
        }
    };
    var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#" + htmlElement), options);
    chart.render();
    return chart;
}
```